.Net Maui Android cannot hide keyboard
UPDATED - Trimmed down user control:
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Platform;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GSL.Presentation.CustomControls;

public partial class GSLEntryControl : ContentView
{

public GSLEntryControl()
{
    try
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"GEORGE: Exception: {ex}");
    }
}

[RelayCommand]
private void ClearText()
{
    Text = string.Empty;
}


// All the updates will be done in the property set. 
public static readonly BindableProperty IsInFocusProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(IsInFocus),
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(GSLEntryControl),
    false,
    BindingMode.OneWay,
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("George: IsInFocusProperty Start");
        if (bindable is GSLEntryControl editText)
        {
            editText.IsInFocus = (bool)newValue;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("George: IsInFocusProperty End");
    });

public string _text = string.Empty;
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return _text;
    }
    set
    {
        //Run all this code on the main UI Thread 
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GEORGE: Text Set Start");
            _text = value;
            //IsClearButtonVisible = _text?.Length > 0;
            //SetBorderColor();
            Debug.WriteLine("GEORGE: Text Set End");
        });
    }
}


private bool _isInFocus = false;
public bool IsInFocus
{
    get
    {
        return _isInFocus;
    }
    set
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"GEORGE: IsInFocus Set Start.  Value: {value}");
        _isInFocus = value;

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
        {

            if (_isInFocus)
            {
                var tempResult = gslEntry.Focus();

            

    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
                    {
#if ANDROID
                        handler.PlatformView.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
#endif
                    });
                //var workResult = await gslEntry.HideSoftInputAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                //Debug.WriteLine($"GEORGE: Focus ShowKeyboard Result: {workResult}");

                Debug.WriteLine($"GEORGE: Focus-KeyBoardShown: {gslEntry.IsSoftKeyboardShowing()}" );
            }
            else
            {
                gslEntry.Unfocus();
            }
            //SetBorderColor();
            Debug.WriteLine("GEORGE: IsInFocus Set End");
        });
    }
}

//When entry is focused, change border color to blue
async void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GEORGE: Entry_Focused start");
    //EntryFocused?.Invoke(sender, e);

    bool workResult = false;
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
        workResult = await gslEntry.HideSoftInputAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        Debug.WriteLine($"GEORGE: Focus ShowKeyboard Result: {workResult}");
    });

    Debug.WriteLine("GEORGE: Entry_Focused end");
}

}
Here is the XAML for the control:

<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <mct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</ContentView.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="entryFrame"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            Padding="0"
            HeightRequest="50"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnDefinitions="*,auto">
            <Entry x:Name="gslEntry"
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       ReturnType="Done"
                       Keyboard="Text"
                       TextTransform="Uppercase"
                       FontSize="16"
                       Text="{Binding Text,Mode=TwoWay}"
                       IsEnabled="True"
                       Placeholder=""
                       IsPassword="False"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Grid.Column="0"/>


            <!-- Clear Button -->
            <ImageButton Source="ic_delete.xml"
                     x:Name="clearButton"
                     WidthRequest="32"
                     HeightRequest="32"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     HorizontalOptions="End"
                     Margin="0,0,5,0"
                     Command="{Binding ClearTextCommand}"
                     Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <Label x:Name="invalidLabel"
           Text="Error"
           Margin="5,0,0,0"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           IsVisible="false"
           Style="{StaticResource ValidationErrorLabelStyle}"
           Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>

I have code in the IsInFocus event to hide the keyboard when an entry control gets focus.  I have tried it several ways including using
HideSoftInputAsync(CancellationToken.None) on the entry control
Using a handler for Android to hide the keyboard as see in the current code.  Neither of these are working.
I also tried adding and removing async from the Dispatcher and event completely removing the Dispatcher and they had no effect.

You can use the handler to hide the softkeyboard.
First, you need to create a custom Entry.
public class NoKeyBoardEntry:Entry{


}

Second, you can add the handler to the GSLEntryControl.xaml.cs to hide the keyboard when you get focus of the.
 public partial class GSLEntryControl : ContentView
    {
    
        public GSLEntryControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NokeyBoard();           
        }
    
    void NokeyBoard()
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
                if (view is NoKeyBoardEntry)
                {
    #if ANDROID
                    handler.PlatformView.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
    
    #endif
                }
            });
        }
    }

Last, you can create the custom entry like this.
<ContentPage

...
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yourProject"
>

<local:NoKeyBoardEntry>


@guangyBai I tried the above suggestion (see updated code) and it had no affect.  I also trimmed down the code a great deal so more simply trouble shoot...

You can try the code handler.PlatformView.GotFocus += (s, e) =>             {                 handler.PlatformView.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;             };  when you got the focus of the entry.

I added that line of code and now I am getting a compilation error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'AppCompatEditText' does not contain a definition for 'GotFocus' and no accessible extension method 'GotFocus' accepting a first argument of type 'AppCompatEditText' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) UserControlTest (net8.0-android) C:\Users\xff7wvm\source\repos\UserControlTest\UserControlTest\CustomControls\GSLEntryControl\GSLEntryControl.xaml.cs 91 Active

I update the answer and you can check it.

OK - So you are basically saying I have to replace the Entry control used in my custom control with the new NoKeyBoardEntry item.  Then add all the code for the handler in my custom control -- I don't understand the last part - creating the custom entry -- wouldn't the be inside my custom control and not on a content page?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/19335715/guangyu-bai-msft I am having success with this approach in my test project.  I am going to move it to my live project to see if it works... Fingers crossed.
Also - What would be the equivalent iOS code for the void NoKeyboard method?

So this does work for me.  As a side note, I did add a tap gesture recognizer to the NoKeybBoardEntry control in my custom control so if the user wanted the keyboard they could tap on the entry control and I will show it.
                    <controls:NoKeyBoardEntry.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                    </controls:NoKeyBoardEntry.GestureRecognizers>


In xaml


<ContentPage ...
               HideSoftInputOnTapped="True">

//rest of the code

</ContentPage> 



This works for me, so whenever you tapped outside of entry or other control keyboard close itself. Works both on ios and android in .net 8 latest version.

This is not quite what I am looking for.  I need to run code and in specific situations, when the entry control gets focus - I do not want to show the keyboard.
